# Adding Hyphen within a spliced string

Tags: python-3.x

Continuing from my last question (which, btw, thanks for the help!), I'm stuck on how to add a hyphen to separate my string. Here's what I have so far:

```
original = "1234567890"
def fixPhoneNum(original):
    original = list(original)
    original[0], original[9] = original[9], original[0]
    original[1:5], original[5:8] = original[5:8], original[1:5]
    original = ''.join(original)
    original = print(original[0:3], end="-"), print(original[3:7], end="-"), print(original[5:9])
    return
```

**Edit The above code doesn't give me the result I'm looking for**

So basically, I took the original string of numbers, switched the first and last  and the intermediary values with each other. Now I want to separate the first 3 digits, the next 3 digits with a hyphen.

Any help? This is driving me crazy.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the expected result, `"956-782-3451"`? Is the string always of length 10?

Comment: Yes. The expected result is 067-862-3451: I fixed the problem by adding the - while it's still a list and before joining it back up (using .insert)

Answer (score 0):

I do not quite understand the rule for character ordering in your question.

Here is a simpler example of `str.format` function which accepts "0123" and produces "30-21" permutation with a hyphen. Hope it answers the question.

```
instr = "0123"
outstr = '{0[3]}{0[0]}-{0[2]}{0[1]}'.format(instr)
```

If you are not familiar with format strings, start with examples in the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatexamples